# Preview stored register locations in a dedicated buffer

Tags: registers

Is it possible save a bunch of point locations into registers and then navigate through them with a preview buffer?

I have tried getting along with `helm-all-mark-rings` and `evil-jumper`, but neither really provide what I am looking for. Currently I just set a bunch of registers to points of interest and fumble my way through jumping back through all of them after I forget which register holds what.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs provides a preview by default, ever since Emacs 24.4.

Just wait a moment after typing <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> and the preview will be displayed.

NEWS.24 details the change:

> *** All interactive commands that read a register (`copy-to-register`, etc.)
> now display a temporary window after `register-preview-delay` seconds
> that summarizes existing registers.  To disable this, set that option to nil.
> Interactive commands that read registers and want to make use of this
> should use `register-read-with-preview` to read register names.

Comment: yes but does not provide a view of the code.

Comment: Ok, I understand the issue now.  I suggest that you `M-x report-emacs-bug` to propose that some of the surrounding text be provided in the preview for context?  It would seem like a good enhancement.

Comment: `C-x r j` is simply `'` when you're in view mode.